# Modify Evolution alarm notifier

Tags: notification, evolution, calendar

Most posts seem to ask how to disable Evolution alarm notifier. Following advice, I installed Evolution, then uninstalled it, in order to maintain sync with my Google calendar. It works! However the notifications come at 7am, which is much too late for me.
Can I change the time at which notifications occur without reinstalling Evolution, possibly  disrupting what took me some time to get working? 75 year old newbie here...
Thanks.